# Arithmetic results requiring axiom of choice

Tags: logic, arithmetic, axiom-of-choice

Are there results in arithmetic (here I mean, theorems involving only integers and operations on them in their formulation) which require (*) the axiom of choice (or Zorn lemma, etc.) to be proven?

(*) If it is not a strict requirement, are there such theorems which have a much more concise proof using the axiom of choice?

Comment: The Countable Union of Countable Sets is Countable is a classic example.